# Selected Value(not selected Text) in Combobox: VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am writing the following code to populate Combobox.

```
strSQL = "Select BankID, BankName As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank"
With Me.cmbBank
  .RowSource = strSQL
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .BoundColumn = 2
  .ColumnWidths = "0in.;1in."
  .ColumnHeads = True
  .LimitToList = True
  .Requery
  .Value = "Please Select Bank"
End With
```

on Button CLick, I am checking combobox selected value and code is here.

```
MsgBox Me.cmbBank.Value
```

It shows Text, Is there any way to get Selected Value(BankID)?

Comment: The output value of the combo equals the bound column, unless you specify the column you want to return. Try `MsgBox Me.cmbBank.Column(0)`

Comment: Change ".BoundColumn = 2" to ".BoundColumn=1". Now "Me.cmbBank.Value" will be the BankID.

Comment: I got the error attached when user is on "Please select Bank" and click Save . Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBGSU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to a valid value of BankID:

```
.Value = "Please Select Bank"
```

or your combo returns *Null* which cause the MsgBox to fail, or correct with *Nz*:

```
MsgBox Nz(Me!cmbBank.Value, "No bank selected.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function Validate() As Boolean

    If IsNull(Me.cmbBank.Column(0)) = True Then
        MsgBox "No bank selected"
        Me.cmbBank.SetFocus
        Validate = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    Validate = True
End Function
```